# Mirror API, 503 response on fetching attachment

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I'm often getting a 503 response when fetching the image attachment to a post. It sometimes works. I'm using the same code as the QuickStart python example.

```
attachment = self.mirror_service.timeline().attachments().get(itemId, attachmentId).execute()
resp, content = self.mirror_service._http.request(attachment['contentUrl'])
```

Has anybody seen this? I thought the credentials had expired, so I tried logging in again, but that does not seem to resolve the problem.

Update: The content returned in the request is "Backend Error".

Comment: Can you please share the body of the HTTP response? It contains an error message which helps troubleshoot issues like these.

Comment: Update the post, the content returned is "Backend Error"

Comment: The problem seems to be resolved. Probably a back-end issue. No idea what was happening,

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have resolved itself.
I assume it was a server side issue.

Comment: Tt started happening again today. Clearly a back-end issue.

Comment: Could you add this issue to our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) and provide us with the timeline item ID and the attachment ID so we can investigate.

Comment: You should indicate this as your answer so this questions doesn't show up in unanswered category.